# How to change checkpoint interval in Yolo 2 (darflow) python?

Tags: python, darkflow

I'm Training Yolo2 (darkflow) and want to change the interval (e.g. every 100 steps) to make checkpoints.

Train command:

```
python flow --model cfg/yolo.cfg --load bin/yolo.weights --train --annotation train/XML --dataset train/Images
```

Something like this:

```
--set ckpt 100
```

I could not find the command. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing line 70 of file flow.py (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/blob/5fe906b347ab8584354e375a14ea2e7bdf5188d7/darkflow/net/flow.py#L70)

```
ckpt = (i+1) % (self.FLAGS.save // self.FLAGS.batch)
```

to

```
  ckpt = (i+1) % 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little bit late but there is no reason to change the code. Here https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow/blob/5fe906b347ab8584354e375a14ea2e7bdf5188d7/darkflow/defaults.py#L31 you can see that there is a cli option to do that.

Just keep in mind that *flow* will save the checkpoint every save // batch_size steps.